# Можно ли пользоваться 2 аккаунтами разработчика в Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

Буду благодарен, если укажете ссылку где можно найти информацию, можно ли пользоваться 2 аккаунтами разработчика  в Google Play.

Один аккаунт я поддерживаю для обновления клиента, а второй использую на своём имени, также планирую поддерживать ещё несколько аккаунтов других клиентов для своевременного обновления приложения.

Comment: Так а в чём вопрос то, собственно? Почему может быть нельзя?

Comment: Не получи ли я потом бан, что пользуюсь разными аккаунтами ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 5):

1. Да, можно использовать/создавать сколько угодно аккаунтов. Но...
2. Если почитать [правила](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2491922?hl=ru&ref_topic=3453554):

   > Если действие вашего аккаунта прекращено из-за нарушения условий для разработчиков, мы не будем принимать от вас никаких приложений. Это означает, что все остальные ваши аккаунты также будут навсегда заблокированы, а все новые аккаунты, которые вы попытаетесь создать, будут удаляться без возврата регистрационного взноса.

   Если Google решат, что какой-то ваш аккаунт нарушает правила, то они больше никогда от вас приложения принимать не будут и будут банить все аккаунты с вами связанные.

Comment: Как же тогда получается после бана, я не смогу больше выкладывать мобильные приложение ?

Comment: @Alex либо быть очень осторожным и не получать бан, либо после бана пытаться скрывать факт того, что вы тот же самый человек, да.